# How to Install a roll-out roof on an almost-flat roof, 16ft x12ft (NJ)

Tags: roofing

This roof has been problematic for me for a long time. It was topped off in asphalt shingles 7 year sago and has started leaking again. I would like to install roll-out roofing. The type that goes on with a torch. To seal things up nicely. The pitch on this roof is VERY slight. it is almost flat.

My plan is to take out the old layers of shingle down to the plywood. Once I have a nice clean plywood surface, What are the next steps?

I cannot afford hiring a roofer. I am physically fit and able. I could really use instructions and links to products. I'm located in NJ. thank you!

Comment: Welcome. That's not what we do here. We answer specific questions about problems or challenges with your project. We don't generate guidebooks and external resource indexes. Please take the [tour] for examples. Product recommendations are specifically off topic. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

The shingle roof was poorly chosen. They require a *significant* slant to the roof, or water will simply "zig zag" up the gap between shingles.

"roll-out" roof isn't very specific. There are several such types; I assume you're asking about the cheapie: modified bitumen.

Cheap. Dumb. Successful. **Pick two**. I think your source of roofing advice isn't very good.  This is a DIY forum, and we're generally *all about* #1 and #3.

Modified bitumen is crud, and that's no secret. It's a cheap "quick-fix" that'll hold a few years.

If you want to do it right, I'd suggest using the *EPDM rubber roof* systems that are offered at lumberyards.  My local lumberyard sells it as wide as 20', which means you could get a 14'x20' sheet and **do your roof in one - no seams**.  Modified bitumen can't do that.

1. Remove **all** existing roofing material. I know it's tempting to just scab another roof on top of the old roof, but that doesn't hold very well in the end.  Get it gone.
2. Carefully remove every single staple, high nail or high screw. Replace any bad nails with deck screws. Replace any faulty OSB sheets.   (remember OSB is not marine plywood, and it is not designed to get wet. It is ruined if waterlogged).
3. Run over the whole roof with a jitterbug 1/4 sheet sander to *make sure* you don't have anything sticking out that would lance a new roof.
4. Make sure that the roof has an edge that's going to play well with the roof material.
5. Apply the rubber roof according to instructions, and use plenty of the specified glue to affix it to the wood sufface.  Do not scrimp on the glue.

Note that the glue costs more than the rubber material itself, but that's fine - it's still pretty cheap for the performance it gives.

Since you can cover the entire roof in one shot, you can avoid some of the other costly parts and  chemicals involved in lap-seams.

Comment: Thank you a ton for this info. Just starting to understand how this forum works. thanks so much!